vue cli installation error with windows 7
I  installed vue cli on my windows 7 and now check my vue version using vue --version command. but now got following error message here
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Nalaka>vue --version
node:os:68
      throw new ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR(ctx);
      ^

SystemError [ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR]: A system error occurred: uv_os_gethostname retur
ned ENOSYS (function not implemented)
    at new Defaults (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinza\node
-ipc\entities\Defaults.js:26:20)
    at new Parser (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinza\node-i
pc\entities\EventParser.js:8:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinz
a\node-ipc\dao\client.js:11:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinz
a\node-ipc\services\IPC.js:4:14) {
  code: 'ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR',
  info: {
    errno: -4054,
    code: 'ENOSYS',
    message: 'function not implemented',
    syscall: 'uv_os_gethostname'
  },
  errno: [Getter/Setter],
  syscall: [Getter/Setter]
}



what is this problem and how to fix this error?

vue-cli is in maintenance mode.  why are you trying to install it?  modern Vue apps are created differently.  try following the official documentation.  if you still for some reason need vue-cli, first let us know actual command you used to install, also what your node version is so we know if you're meeting minimum installation requirement.

@yoduh using node 16.16.0 and now I need install vue cli for create new vue js 3 project

@Matakoththuwakoni Node version is too new and not supported in w7. And you'll have problems with using current versions of most tools with node version (12) that is supported in w7, it was released 5y ago, so only the packages that were released at that time are guaranteed to work. I'd suggest to upgrade at least to w10 to  avoid problems. Vue CLI is abandoned and Vite is officially recommended for new vue projects. But you'll have even more problems with it because it didn't even exist 5y ago
